# React use SVGR with svg in public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, svg-react-loader

Is there any way I can import an SVG file in my public folder as a React component like so :

```js
import { ReactComponent as MySvg } from '/assets/svg/mysvg.svg';

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MySvg />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

I know there are workarounds like using an `img` tag but I really need my SVG to be used as a React component...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score -1):

You can copy & paste the svg code in a js file like this:

```
const MySvg = () => (
    <svg viewBox=...>....</svg>
)
```

then, you can use it like this:

```
<MySvg />
```

Comment: Thank you ! what if I have subfolders in my SVG folder ?

Comment: @LouisLecouturier options: {
          publicPath: 'assets',
        },

Comment: it doesn't seem to work... my imports are not being changed when the app is running `ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/assets/svg/icons/sellers/stats/star.svg' in '/Users/louislecouturier/Documents/Resply/src/resply/libs/ui-kit/common/src/lib/Common/Misc/Data/Rate`

Comment: @LouisLecouturier I changed the answer with another method, check it out... I hope it works for you